# Can I get a fingerprint of an ec key, using openssl?

Tags: openssl

Can I get a fingerprint of an ec key, using openssl?

Running `openssl ec -in keys/secp256k1.pub.pem -fingerprint` gives an error telling me that `-fingerprint` is not an option.

Comment: EC public keys are already about the length of hash functions used for fingerprints.

Comment: @otus Is there therefore no standard for EC fingerprints?

Comment: @otus That may not be the case for the entire encoded key, presuming it contains at least the name (or OID) of the domain parameters or even worse, the parameters themselves (+ ASN.1 overhead).

Comment: There is not A standard. 
Fingerprints are often used for X.509 *certificates* but that is not the same as the public key. 
X.509 certificates often contain a hash of the public key value as SubjectKeyId (and AuthorityKeyId in a child cert), 
but this is not called a fingerprint, and the format OpenSSL uses for a (separate) public key is the SubjectPublicKeyInfo 
(SPKI) from X.509, which is not the correct value to hash.  
**SSH** frequently uses fingerprints of new server public keys 
for manual verification (supposedly), for all supported algorithms (RSA DSA as well as ECDSA), ...

Comment: ... using the SSH public-key format which is different from OpenSSL's.
**PGP** defines fingerprint as a hash of the public key in PGP packet format, different from either SSH's or OpenSSL's;
again this is the same for all algorithms, and ECC was only recently specified for PGP and is not yet much used.
In modern PGP the keyid for a key is the low bits of the fingerprint, and often the keyid is used rather than the full fingerprint.
**Short answer:** you can do X.509 SKI with commandline and a little trickery; you could do the others with libcrypto and code but SSH and PGP programs are easier.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
openssl x509 -noout -pubkey -in cert.pem | openssl ec -pubin -outform d | dd ibs=26 skip=1 | openssl dgst -sha256
```

To find the correct `ibs` you may need to double check with `asn1parse`

Comment: It worked for me as well. Finally found the answer. It would help if you can provide some example / info on using asn1parse to check the ibs